# Predict() has less lines than original data in R

Tags: r

I am trying to predict the survival probability given a set of variables. Here is my code:

```
ID <- c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F")
age <- c(54, 61, 65, 55, 60, 60)
sex <- c(0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0)
Q1 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
Q2 <- c(0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1) 
Q3 <- c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1) 
Q4 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1) 
Q5 <- c(0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1)
E1 <- c(2, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)
E2 <- c(0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 0)
E3 <- c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
E4 <- c(1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)
E5 <- c(0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 2)
Sint <- c(4, 3, 4, 1, 0, 2)
surv1 <- c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
surv2 <- c(1, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1)
surv3 <- c(1, NA, 0, 1, 1, 1)
surv4 <- c(1, NA, 0, 1, 1, 0)
surv5 <- c(1, NA, 0, 1, NA, 0)
surv6 <- c(1, NA, 0, 1, NA, 0)


dta <- data.frame(ID, age, sex, Q1, Q2, Q3, Q4, Q5, E1, E2, E3, E4, E5, Sint,
                  surv1, surv2, surv3, surv4, surv5, surv6)

# Arrays
surv_wave <- c("surv1", "surv2", "surv3", "surv4", "surv5", "surv6")
predictors_fix <- c("age", "sex", "Sint")
predictors_Q <- c("Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q5")
predictors_E <- c("E1", "E2", "E3", "E4", "E5")


# Survival denominator
# Probability variables that will be predicted
dta$wsd2 <- NA
dta$wsd3 <- NA
dta$wsd4 <- NA
dta$wsd5 <- NA
dta$wsd6 <- NA

# vector of variables that will be predicted
wsurv_den <- c("wsd2", "wsd3", "wsd4", "wsd5", "wsd6")

# iterate all waves
for(i in 2:6) {
  
  # subset people who survived in the previous wave
  Subset <- subset(dta, dta[[surv_wave[i-1]]] == 1)
  
  # logistic regression
  f <- as.formula(
    paste(surv_wave[i], 
          paste(c(predictors_fix, predictors_Q[i-1], predictors_E[i-1]),
                collapse=" + "),
          sep = "~"))
  Den_surv_s <- glm(f,  family = binomial(link = "logit"), na.action=na.exclude, 
                    data = Subset)
  
  # predict probabilities of survival based on logistic regression
  Den_surv_p_s <- predict(Den_surv_s, type = "response")
  
  # Add predicted values to original dataset
  dta[dta[[surv_wave[i-1]]] == 1,][[wsurv_den[i-1]]]<-Den_surv_p_s
  
}
```

I get this error:

```
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, wsurv_den[i - 1], value = c(`1` = 0.999999999941738,  : 
  replacement has 4 rows, data has 5
```

I understand I am getting this error because the first line of my for loop is excluding those with NAs in addition to the ones with 0, and the last line is not excluding the NAs, therefore the difference in rows.

How can I modify my code to correctly assign my predictions?

Comment: I'm sure you checked a few `i`s manually. Did you notice that the `Den_surv_p_s` are named with numbers? These are the observation (row) numbers that you can account for in the last line of your loop.

Comment: This is a `NA`'s issue: see that `dta[[ surv_wave[i - 1] ]] == 1` only gives 4 `TRUE`values and to subset based on it will givw you `nrow(Subset)` equal to 4. Then, in the last loop code line, you assign 4 values to a 5 rows data.frame.

Comment: Also, typo: `f <- f <- as.formula(` !

Answer (score 0):

This loop works. I have made the following changes:

- `which()` removes `NA`'s from logical conditions;
- `predictors` vector created early in the loop;
- the two vectors in the previous points are used as row and column indices to subset the data;
- no `paste` and `as.formula` gymnastics, `reformulate` is the right way to create a regression formula.

And here is the final code.

```
# iterate all waves
for(i in 2:6) {
  # index to subset dta
  i_surv <- which(dta[[ surv_wave[i-1] ]] == 1)
  predictors <- c(predictors_fix, predictors_Q[i-1], predictors_E[i-1])
  
  # subset people who survived in the previous wave
  # and keeping only the current predictors
  Subset <- dta[i_surv, predictors]

  # logistic regression
  f <- reformulate(termlabels = predictors, response = surv_wave[i])
  
  Den_surv_s <- glm(f,  family = binomial(link = "logit"), 
                    na.action = na.exclude, 
                    data = Subset)
  
  # predict probabilities of survival based on logistic regression
  Den_surv_p_s <- predict(Den_surv_s, type = "response")
  
  # Add predicted values to original dataset
  dta[i_surv, wsurv_den[i-1] ] <- Den_surv_p_s
}
```

With only the new variables shown, the result is

```
dta[wsurv_den]
#          wsd2 wsd3         wsd4 wsd5 wsd6
#1 1.000000e+00    1 1.000000e+00    1    1
#2           NA   NA           NA   NA   NA
#3 2.143345e-11   NA           NA   NA   NA
#4 1.000000e+00    1 1.000000e+00    1    1
#5 1.000000e+00    1 1.000000e+00   NA   NA
#6 1.000000e+00    1 5.826215e-11   NA   NA
```

Comment: Thank you, I will look into reformulate. I am now getting another error messade: Error in model.frame.default(formula = f, data = Subset, na.action = na.exclude,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for 'age')

Comment: @nattys What is the value of `i` when you get that error?

Comment: i = 3. What is happening is that now the predict has 6 rows and the data has 4 rows

Comment: @nattys I am not getting that result. For i=3, I have `surv_wave[i-1]` is `"surv2"` and `dta[["surv2"]]` is `[1]  1 NA  0  1  1  1` which has only 4 valid values. Maybe there's something in your R session interfering with the variables, can you restart R and run the code again?

Comment: I restarted and unfortunately still get the error. I was able to solve the problem by modifying the last line in my original code to: ```dta[dta[[surv_wave[i-1]]] == 1 & !is.na(dta[[surv_wave[i-1]]),][[wsurv_den[i-1]]]<-Den_surv_p_s```
I will now change my code to use ```reformulate``` instead of ```paste``` and ```as.formula```. Thank you for all your help.